# Ignore read data and close socket

Tags: c++, apache, sockets, http, networking

I am making a Web Server Library. Whenever a connection is made I parse the HTTP Header and ignore the content to be read afterwards. If the content was not intended to be read then the socket is closed. Is this a good way because I don't want anyone to send a huge content with the header and I keep parsing it the whole day.

Comment: Closing the socket before reading all of the data is fine, it won't hurt anything.

Comment: What are your plans for handling POST requests with multiple megabytes worth of content?

Comment: Many HTTP clients will send an `Expect: 100-continue` request header, allowing the server to send back an `100 Continue` informational response, before then sending large content.